# No Internet on my Ubuntu 20 box, How do I restart network related items if I do not have ifconfig for ifup ifdown?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ifconfig

I need to restart my networking in ubuntu 20 as I do not have ifconfig or ifdown or ifup. Right now my vps ubuntu box has no internet, and I am logged in via the web console. When I do a ping 8.8.8.8, I do not get a response and it doesnt look like it can reach repositories for me to do apt install ifconfig neither. I want to try to turn off and on the networking to see if that works. Or is there another way to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `iproute2` commands:

Temporary ip assignment:

```
sudo ip addr add ip/24 dev <interface>
ip link set dev <interface> up
sudo ip route add default via <gateway>
```

Persistent ip assignment:

edit `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml` file , here is an example for dhcp:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    <interface>:
      dhcp4: true
```

Then run:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

[Netplan configuration examples](https://netplan.io/examples/)